# Behavior not working in inheritance sometimes

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I found strange behavior when using Behavior. I want to animate the height of a Pane when I changed the Pane's height:

ModulePanelCard.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1

Pane{
    id: root
    property bool isToggled: true
    Material.elevation: 6

    height: root.isToggled? 300: 100
    Behavior on height {
        NumberAnimation{duration: 300}
    }

    Button{
        text: "click"
        anchors{top: parent.top; right: parent.right; left: parent.left}
        height: 40
        onClicked: root.isToggled = !root.isToggled
    }

}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1
import QtQuick 2.6

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    ModulePanelCard{
        id: strategyCard
        width: 300
        anchors{top:parent.top; right: parent.right; left: parent.left}
    }
}
```

OK. The animation shows up and everything goes fine! However when I want to do some inheritance, i.e. inherit from `ModulePanelCard`, strange things happen:

StrategyCard.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7

ModulePanelCard{
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1
import QtQuick 2.6

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    StrategyCard{
        id: strategyCard
        width: 300
        anchors{top:parent.top; right: parent.right; left: parent.left}
    }
}
```

If I put nothing into `StrategyCard`, everything is the same as previous. However, when I insert even one property or signal to `StrategyCard`, the animation of the height is just gone! The Behavior on the height won't work anymore!

StategyCard.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7

ModulePanelCard{
    property string xxx: "hello"
}
```

However, if I put the Behavior statement into StrategyCard.qml, then the animation comes back!

New StrategyCard.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7

ModulePanelCard{
    property string xxx: "hello"
    Behavior on height {
        NumberAnimation{duration: 300}
    }
}
```

What happened? Anyone helps me? Thanks!

My development environment is: Windows 10 64bit, Qt 5.9.0 64bit for VS2015, Qt Creator 4.3.0